# How can I find the last success commit based for a job under a workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using this action `https://github.com/SamhammerAG/last-successful-build-action` which gives me the last success commit based on the workflow name. My workflow includes a matrix which scales up to many concurrent jobs. Is there a way to find the last success job (based on its name) under a specified workflow?

There could be many runs for that workflow so it needs to find all the runs from the entire history in order to get the last success one. That makes me think it is a bit hard to do. Does github support query it in an easy way?

Comment: Have you looked at [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) i.e. `gh workflow` and `gh run` commands?